# set windowlightstatusbar property programmatically

Tags: android, android-statusbar

As you know we can set the `windowLightStatusBar` from xml by following codes.

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

i need to change this attribute true to false or false to true by programmatically. Is there a way to achive it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

set this if you want to change icons colors

```
.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_‌​BAR);
```

and to reset to default set this

```
.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
```

but if you want to change background color of statusBar use this

```
getWindow.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

[Update for API 26]

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    window.insetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance(WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS,
             WindowInsetsController.APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS)
} else {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
    } else {
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
    }
    
}
```

and to clear it

```
window.insetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance(0, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS)
```

Comment: when i set "windowLightStatusBar" = true then the icon color of status bar becomes gray. but if i set it false then it becomes white. as far as i am concerned from your code you set it to true by using ".setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_‌​BAR);". So how can i set it false by programmatically?

Comment: .setSystemUiVisibility(0); test this

Answer (score 22):

I believe this is the correct way to turn on and turn off.

```
if (on) {
    View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(view.getSystemUiVisibility() | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
} else {
    View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(view.getSystemUiVisibility() & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
}
```

Comment: The only way that always works in both directions. But only for API<30. Unfortunately, couldn't find the way to do the same with `WindowInsetsController` on API 30+.

Answer (score 14):

Hidro's answer is almost correct, but WindowInsetsControllerCompat needs to be called as a function to work, otherwise it claims there is an unresolved reference in my case.

For Kotlin:

```
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, yourView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
```

For Java:

```
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(getWindow(), yourView).setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true)
```

Comment: `yourView` can just be `WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView)`

Comment: @TongJingYen status bar's icons is still black after set isAppearanceLightStatusBars  to false

Comment: If you set `android:windowLightStatusBar` in the styles, this won't work. You need to call the deprecated function to disable the system UI flag.

Comment: for java: new WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.getDecorView()).setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);

Comment: Got this working like this:
`WindowInsetsControllerCompat(requireActivity().window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = false`, was calling this from onViewCreated() in fragment. Works great on api 26...33

Answer (score 8):

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
```

**Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
    }
}
```

Tested on Android 8 and Android 12. Work well

Answer (score 7):

To clear this attribute, use this code:

```
window.clearFlags( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `View.setSystemUiVisibility()` is deprecated from API 30 in favor of the new `WindowInsetsController` API, the 2021 answer to this one is now [`WindowInsetsControllerCompat#setAppearanceLightStatusBars(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat#setAppearanceLightStatusBars(boolean)), which is backward compatible to API 23. Required [`androidx.core:core:1.5.0-alpha05`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions#1.5.0-alpha05) or later.

```kotlin
WindowInsetsControllerCompat.setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true)
```

Comment: It's an instance method, so you will need to create an instance of WindowInsetsControllerCompat first.

Answer (score 1):

Only do this
 it make icon color white

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

### **In Activity**

If you want change the windowLightStatusBar inside the activity

**For Kotlin**

```
val windowInsetController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window,window.decorView)
    windowInsetController.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
```

**For Java**

```
WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());
        windowInsetController.setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);
```

### **In Fragment**

And if you want change the windowLightStatusBar inside the fragment

**For Kotlin**

```
  val windowInsetController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(requireActivity().window,requireActivity().window.decorView)
        windowInsetController.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
```

**For Java**

```
WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(requireActivity().getWindow(), requireActivity().getWindow().getDecorView());
        windowInsetController.setAppearanceLightStatusBars(true);
```